# First login logic not working in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a logic in my app where if it's the first time the user is logging in he'll see a password signup page else he'll be redirected to the dashboard. Following is the existing code:

```
...
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {firstLogin: null}
}

componentWillMount = () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('isLogged') )
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
  };

componentDidUpdate = () => {    
  try {
    const firstLogin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('clientUser')).first_login;
      this.setState({firstLogin});
  }
  catch (e) {
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem('isLogged')) {
   if (this.state.firstLogin)
      this.setState({firstLogin: true});
    else
      this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
  }
};

render() {
  return (
    {this.state.firstLogin ? 
    <div>
     //account setup page
    </div> :
    <div>
    //login page
    </div>}
  )
}
```

This code is not working as expected and is stuck in a loop. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some check in `componentDidUpdate`, otherwise it'll repeatedly execute `this.setState({ firstLogin })` (as it triggers `componentDidUpdate`) and cause the infinite recursion.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (!this.state.firstLogin) {
    // insert code to get `firstLogin`
    this.setState({ firstLogin });
  };
}
```